# Multithreaded FTP Server in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm making a multithreaded FTP server in Java and I have a question about to go about handling multiple clients. Right now, I have a Server that looks like this:

```
public class Server {
private static final int HOST_PORT = 6000;

private ServerSocket serverSocket;

public Server(ServerModel serverModel) throws IOException {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(HOST_PORT);
}

public void start() {
    try {
        acceptClients();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void acceptClients() throws IOException {
    while (true) {
        Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
        ServerModel serverModel = new ServerModel();
        Thread worker = new Thread(new ServerWorker(client, serverModel));
        worker.start();
    }
}
```

}

And a ServerWorker object which is responsible for interpreting client commands and responding to them:

```
public class ServerWorker implements Runnable {

private ServerRemoteHandler serverRemoteHandler;
private ServerModel serverModel;

private static final int GET_CODE = 1;
private static final int PUSH_CODE = 2;
private static final int CHANGE_DIRECTORY_CODE = 3;
private static final int PRINT_WORKING_DIRECTORY_CODE = 4;
private static final int FILE_EXISTS_CODE = 5;
private static final int LIST_FILES_DIRECTORIES_CODE = 6;
private static final int EXIT_CODE = 0;

public ServerWorker(Socket client, ServerModel serverModel) throws IOException {
    this.serverModel = serverModel;

    try {
        serverRemoteHandler = new ServerRemoteHandler(client);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void parseCommand() {
    int command;

    try {
        while (true) {
            command = serverRemoteHandler.getCommand();
            switch (command) {
            case CHANGE_DIRECTORY_CODE:
                changeDirectory();
                break;
            case PRINT_WORKING_DIRECTORY_CODE:
                printWorkingDirectory();
                break;
            case FILE_EXISTS_CODE:
                fileExists();
                break;
            case LIST_FILES_DIRECTORIES_CODE:
                listFilesDirectories();
                break;
            case GET_CODE:
                pushFile();
                break;
            case PUSH_CODE:
                getFile();
                break;
            case EXIT_CODE:
                exit();
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        exit();
    }
}

private void printWorkingDirectory() throws IOException {
    serverRemoteHandler.printWorkingDirectory(serverModel.getCurrentPath());
}

private void changeDirectory() throws IOException {
    String fileName = serverRemoteHandler.getFileName();
    boolean success = serverModel.changeDirectory(fileName);

    serverRemoteHandler.changeDirectory(success);
}

private void fileExists() throws IOException {
    String fileName = serverRemoteHandler.getFileName();
    serverRemoteHandler.fileExists(serverModel.fileExists(fileName));
}

private void pushFile() throws IOException {
    File file = serverModel.getFile(serverRemoteHandler.getFileName());
    long fileSize = serverModel.getFileSize(file);

    serverRemoteHandler.pushFile(file, fileSize);
}

private void listFilesDirectories() throws IOException {
    serverRemoteHandler.listFilesDirectories(serverModel.listFilesDirectories());
}

private void getFile() throws IOException {
    String fileName = serverRemoteHandler.getFileName();
    File file = new File(serverModel.getCurrentPath() + File.separator + fileName);

    serverRemoteHandler.getFile(file);
}

private void exit() {
    serverRemoteHandler.exit();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        parseCommand();
    }
}
```

}

Each ServerWorker has an Object called RemoteHandler whose job is to send and receive information from the streams. My questions are regarding this line:

```
Thread worker = new Thread(new ServerWorker(client, serverModel));
```

Is this thread safe? Is this a good way of implementing it? Thank you.

Comment: Do you really need all three of `ServerWorker, ServerModel,` and `ServerRemoteHandler`? Seems a bit over-factored to me.

Comment: The Model is really just a utility class that returns info on files. The Remote handler abstracts all of the network interactions away, and the server worker implements runnable. Do you recommend doing it differently?

Comment: Not really. I might have done it more simply but what you say sounds reasonable.

Comment: I realize this is not for discussion, but briefly out of curiosity, how would you have done it? Always curious how to better design this stuff.

Comment: Just glancing quickly above, I would probably not have `ServerRemoteHandler` at all, and I would certainly put *all* the file system stuff like `changeDirectory()` into the `ServerModel`, which I might rename to something about a remote file system client view. But then I've never been an MVC fan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is threadsafe. Everything in that line is method-local, so it is only accessible by the current thread, and then the worker thread starts while this one loops and gets a new set of values for these variables.

(That doesn't imply the entire program is thread-safe, of course.)

Comment: Great, thanks so much. I have one more question. Since each thread is getting a new Runnable object, isn't it inherently thread safe since there are no shared variables?

Comment: @namarino41 That's correct. Avoid shared variables and you avoid thread-safety issues. That includes `static` variables of course.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Thanks so much for the help, it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: Agreed, method local will be in stack as long as nothing is shared between serverSocket class, which is not method local. Good Luck :)

Comment: @amitmah Method-local variables are on the stack, period. The rest of that has nothing to do with it. The question had already been answered. You're just causing confusion.